# how to Identify which Macro is Assigned To A shape

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to get to know that which Macro/Code is assigned to a specific Shape.

Comment: Right-click and choose Assign macro?

Comment: Thank you very much @Rory. I was searching it for long and it was quite hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can check what macro assign on each shape, if you know specific shape name or text just add If :)

```
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects
     MsgBox shp.OnAction
Next shp
```

Comment: This is quite helpful.  I have inherited a spreadsheet with many buttons and with this code I can inventory all shapes and what they are doing.